# Is it allowed to use two WHERE clauses in FQL?

Tags: php, facebook-fql, where-clause

I am trying to use two WHERE clauses in one fql query

```
SELECT uid, pic, pic_square, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND WHERE strstr('ab',name)
```

but getting error

```
Parser error: unexpected 'WHERE' at position
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its enough to use AND like:

```
SELECT .... 
FROM ..... 
WHERE ((Condition A) AND (Condition B))
```

Answer (score 0):

Either the closing bracket is wrong, or you miss a complete (second) subselect clause.

```
SELECT uid, pic, pic_square, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()    ====>>) AND ====>>WHERE strstr('ab',name)
```